# How to set the height with css to 100% and make it fluid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get sth like container-fluid in bootstrap for the height. I want the .button Elements to scale automatically according to the height and the width of the website. Wondering how i have to set my with so it scales.

http://jsbin.com/sujejimebe/7/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it can be helpfull, read more about vh property in CSS:
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

Comment: Thanks perfect exactly what I needed!The only thing I noticed is that it doesn't fill in the complete viewport height but leaves a little grey area at the bottom.

Comment: Can you do SS? are you check body/html margins? Because vh must fill full height

Comment: There is two small issues. http://imgur.com/FF02s63 + http://imgur.com/sCjb4sf 

The small border on the bottom and the not perfectly aligned 0 key...
The 0 key probably has to do with the margin-right: -4px; on the .button class. Don't know how to avoid that.

Comment: Fixed the issue by setting row height. And floating left and removing margins.